# select 'id' in every table psql

Tags: postgresql

Each table in my database ([see schema](https://betydb.org)) has a primary key called `id`.

I would like to find all records in all tables where id is in the range [1,1000]. How can I write such a query?

I've tried to write a for loop following the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

```
FOR T IN (
  SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema. TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'public'
    )
LOOP
    SELECT id, T FROM T WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
  RETURN NEXT T;
END LOOP ;
```

but get "Syntax error at FOR".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in one statement pretty easily.

```
SELECT string_agg(statement, E'\nUNION ALL ') || ';'
FROM (
  SELECT FORMAT(
    $$SELECT '%s' AS table_catalog, '%s' AS table_schema, '%s' AS table_name, id FROM %I.%I.%I WHERE %I BETWEEN 1 AND 1000$$,
    table_catalog,
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    table_catalog,
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    column_name
  )
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE
    table_catalog = CURRENT_CATALOG
    AND table_schema = 'public'
    AND column_name = 'id'
) AS t(statement);
```

That will generate a single statement. In `psql`, just run `\gexec` after that.

Comment: PS for reference here is my final script https://gist.github.com/dlebauer/f586e380fa4cfadc25551cd1df487b7d. It still required me to 1) split the multipolygon, 2) string substitution like `sed 's/({1},//g'` and 3) sort by xmax in order to organize EW and 4) concatenating insert statements. I did 1 in psql and 2-4 in google sheets. A solution all in psql would be neat, but not necessary (to me) at this point b/c this solution worked. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure how any of that is related to the question, but cool. ;) PostGIS rocks.

Comment: Sorry that was related to a totally different  question!